# Необходимо, чтобы  при нажатии на картинку, она выводилась в другой блок

Tags: html

Как мне реализовать, чтоб картинка выводилась как на сайте [http://фотостатусы.рф](http://фотостатусы.рф/мультфильмы/).
Необязательно чтоб нарезанная, а чтобы при клике на определённую картинку она показывалась сверху, типа её выбрали.

Comment: а исходный код сайта посмотреть вера или знания не позволяют?

Comment: Вы издеваетесь такую ссылку давать? Может мне еще регистрироваться надо чтобы попытаться найти то, что вам надо!!!

Comment: Начал делать, докончу выложу код в ответ, ждите...

Comment: @Антон_Мухин, а чем вам ссылка не угодила. Зашел посмотрел. По клику на картинку меняется картинка в шапке. Все как хочет ТС. @knes вот не погнушался показать, как это делается.

Comment: @AmP Всё, я выложил ответ, посмотрите ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как обещал, вот кроссбраузерный код (на нативе как я люблю):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Перетаскивание DIV`а</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .imgs {
            height: 50px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            z-index: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function imgClick(evt){
            lastSelected.style.zIndex = "0";
            var imgObj = window.event ? event.srcElement : evt.target
            imgObj.style.zIndex = "1";
            lastSelected = imgObj;
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
                if(imgs[i].className.indexOf("imgs") != -1){
                    imgs[i].onclick = imgClick;
                }
            }
            window.lastSelected = imgs[0];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img class="imgs" style="position: absolute;left: 0px;" src="" alt="Изображение1">
<img class="imgs" style="position: absolute;left: 40px;" src="" alt="Изображение2">
<img class="imgs" style="position: absolute;left: 80px;" src="" alt="Изображение3">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: > код (на нативе как я люблю)

+1

Comment: Ну это вообще шик. Единственное(ну, можно ложечку дегтя? =) ), класс .imgs слабо связан с переменной imgs. То есть, событие будет происходить при нажатии абсолютно на любой имидж, а не только на определенную выборку. +1

Comment: Спасибо, @knes, исправил (вручную проверку класса дописал т.к. getElementsByClassName не кросбраузерный а ф-цию ради выборки для примера работы копипастить сюда не хотел)  
+1 вашему ответу

Answer (score 3):

Ну, типа, так:

```
<img class="clickmeclass" src="image1.jpg" />
.....
<img class="clickmeclass" src="image100500.jpg" />
<img id="showhereblock" src="default.jpg" />
<script>
$(".clickmeclass").click(function(){
$("#showhereblock").attr('src') = $(this).attr('src');
});
</script>
```

Не забудте подключить jquery.

P.S. обращение к народу(типа, безличное, но...):
НАРОД! Ты чего такой злой? Если вам **лень** делать простое задание по ответу на вопрос, оставьте возможность новичкам поучаствовать. Не надо столько желчи: иногда "зеленым" правда сложно разобраться в большом объеме скриптов. Для этого и существует этот форум.
Профессионалы могут и на Стэке поискать.
Если вопрос действительно не заслуживает внимания и должен быть удален, поставьте минус. Еще лучше, если вы снабдите пост комментарием с прямым указанием на ошибку автора.
Пример:

> По предоставленной ссылке требуется
> регистрация, поэтому просьба
> предоставить другую ссылку, либо кусок
> кода. Ссылки на внешние источники
> могут рассматриваться как реклама, что
> противоречит правилам форума.

Просто складывается впечатление, что вода становится менее мокрая, трава менее зеленая, а атмосфера менее дружественная, чем раньше.

Comment: > Просто складывается впечатление, что вода становится менее мокрая, трава менее зеленая, а атмосфера менее дружественная, чем раньше

Согласен, есть такое ощущение. В последнее время наиболее употребляемые ответы: "Никто тебе этого не будет делать", "А самому поискать", "Вопрос ни о чем" и т. п.

Comment: Согласен с @knes @Nofate вот цитата @Spectre на вопрос @AlexWindHope (Uuencoding в JavaScript):  
@AlexWindHope:

>Доброго времени - интересует рабочая функция для преобразования строки в UUencode.

@Spectre:

>хотел вставить коммент про завершение учебных заданий, а потом на ник обратил внимание, передумал

А если бы участник был без репутации (новичок) его бы "задавили".Меня тоже по началу "давили" и "тролилли" но набрал репутацию наоборот плюсовать стали (в том числе за вопросы/ответы которые раньше сами минусовали). Вообще странный народ тут собрался :)

Comment: Ребята, большое всем спасибо за помощь, особенно @Rules и @knes. Я использовал более простой способ. Поясняю:
допустим где то в документе у нас есть  блок с картинкой:
<div id="photo_preview" >
<img id="default" src=""/>
</div>
вот мне было необходимо, чтобы в этом месте при нажатии на картинку, а именно на одну из этих:

<div class="crop">
<img src="img/win_ipad_small.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="crop">
<img src="img/win_ipad_small1.jpg"/>
</div>

Comment: выводилась соответствующая в верхнем блоке. я использовал следующую конструкцию 
<img src="img/win_ipad_small.jpg" onClick='document.all.default.src="img/win_ipad_small.jpg"'/>

Вот, собственно, и всё. Я знаю, что некорректно задал вопрос, ну я только учусь!

Comment: @AmP, это более простой но менее правильный способ. Лучше внимательно прочитайте что написал @Rules. Он дело написал. Так правильно, ибо отделяет мух от котлет. В разметке должна быть разметка, а в скриптах - скрипты.

Comment: Хорошо, перечитаю и переделаю!